# Convert CustomList to String/Array

Tags: java, list, join, custom-lists, toarray

I have a CustomList which does everything as needed until I encountered that code like `String.join(" ", list)` or `list.toArray(String[]::new)` doesn't work with my CustomList but works with ArrayList. What am I doing wrong?

CustomList adds and removes every element in pairs.

```
class CustomList implements List<String> {

    private List<String> list;

    public CustomList() {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

//implemented overridden methods
}
```

`String.join(" ", list)` throws a NullPointerException.
`list.toArray(String[]::new)` returns null.

```
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        list.toArray(a);
        return a;
    }

    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }
```

Comment: Please show us your `iterator()` and `toArray()` methods. For `String.join(" ", list)` you need to implement `Iterable` which is at least the `iterator()` method. If you just return `null`, then it will fail at runtime with an NPE.

Comment: I added the methods.

Comment: I suggest you append the entire source code of your class to the Question, along with example usage.

Answer (score 0):

`list.toArray(String[]::new)` doesn't compile for me.
Perhaps, the way you use the class is wrong.

I implemented the methods:

```
@Override
public Iterator<String> iterator() {
    return list.iterator();
}

@Override
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    return list.toArray(a); // Better not to return a, but should work either way.
}
```

Then I tested the `CustomList`:

```
CustomList strings = new CustomList();
strings.addAll(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));

Iterator<String> iterator = strings.iterator();
String firstStr = iterator.next();
System.out.println("Iterator test: "+ firstStr);

String[] arr = new String[strings.size()];
strings.toArray(arr);
System.out.println("toArray() test: "+ Arrays.toString(arr));

String join = String.join(" ", strings);
System.out.println("String.join test: "+join);
```

Output:

```
Iterator test: A
toArray() test: [A, B, C]
String.join test: A B C
```